# Static UITableView is showing separator lines when they have been disabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have static UITableView embed in a UIContainerView. The tableView is showing separator lines when I have disabled them.

[image: UITableView Configuration]

[image]

Comment: That's the table view style. Change the style from plain to grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My UITableViewController was extending a custom UITableViewController, this was adding custom separators.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom offset like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Objective C -

`self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Swift -

`self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)`

If works please reply. We need to hit and trial as the details provided is not sufficient to track down the problem. Also if not works, please post code if you have.